# ImportError: No module named "user_models"

Tags: python, linux, python-venv, amazon-lightsail

I have the following structure on my server:

```
/var/www/catalog
    |-- catalog.wsgi
    |__ /catalog             
         |-- __init__.py
         |-- data.py
         |-- database.py
         |-- /models
              |-- __init__.py
              |-- category.py
              |-- item.py
              |__ user_models.py   
         |-- /static
              |__ styles.css
         |-- /templates
              |-- about.html
              |-- base.html
              |-- categories.html
              |-- delete_item.html 
              |-- edit_item.html
              |-- login.html
              |-- new_item.html
              |__ show_item.html
         |-- /utils
              |__ lorem_ipsum_generator.py
         |-- /venv3          # Virtual Environment
         |__ /views
              |-- __init__.py
              |-- about.py
              |-- api.py
              |-- auth.py
              |-- category_view.py
              |-- item_view.py
              |__ user_view.py
```

when I start the venv and try to do

```
python __init__.py
```

it shows me

```
File "__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from views.category_view import category
  File "/var/www/catalog/catalog/views/category_view.py", line 5, in <module>
    from models.category import Category
  File "/var/www/catalog/catalog/models/category.py", line 8, in <module>
    from user_models import User
ImportError: No module named 'user_models'
```

inside the /models/category.py file I use this

```
from user_models import User
```

Hope somebody can help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Django for this project? Have you tried something like `from models.user_models import User`?

Comment: I solved the problem by adding "_models" to all files in the models directory and "_views" to all files in the views directory. (e.g. /models/category.py changed to /models/category_models.py)

and of course @zmike you´re right I needed to add models. in front of user_models. Thank you very much!

I´m not quite sure why python has problems if the file names are the same but in different directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like `from models.user_models import`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding "_models" to all files in the models directory and "_views" to all files in the views directory. (e.g. /models/category.py changed to /models/category_models.py) and of course @zmike you´re right I needed to add models. in front of user_models. Thank you very much! I´m not quite sure why python has problems if the file names are the same but in different directory